# How to use android webview for incognito tab?

Tags: java, android, webview, incognito-mode

I'm writing a light browser for my website and have to create incognito tab like chrome. I have used android `webview`. My problem is that when I use `webview` I can't save the cookies in a temporary location and delete the cookies file after the incognito tab is closed.
this is my code:

```
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    if (this.isIncognito) {
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
    } else {
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
```

how should I save cookies and delete it after closing tab?

Comment: To launch a WebView in private mode in Android you have to clear all the history and cache stored by the webview.

Answer (score 0):

To launch a WebView in private mode in Android you have to clear all the history and cache stored by the webview.

```
        // init webview
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Enable private browsing mode
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(false);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(false);

        // Load a URL in the WebView
        webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```

and in onDestroy clear all stored cache and data by the webview.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy WebView to free resources
        if (webView != null) {
            webView.clearHistory();
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
            webView.onPause();
            webView.removeAllViews();
            webView.destroyDrawingCache();
            webView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

or It is better to use Chrome Custom Tabs for opening URLs inside your app. Follow this link for more details https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/guide-get-started/